# Modal link doesn't work the second time it's clicked using jquery and twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.0, modal-dialog

I have some data displayed in DataTables jquery plugin. I have a hidden modal that I set the html on, and then show when a user clicks on a table row to edit it. It works the first time it's clicked, but after that, it will not open the modal unless the page is reloaded. I get the error: *"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"* at line containing *#modal-editUser* below.

My on click:

```
<script style="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.edit-record', function(e) {
        alert("edit contact" + $("#modal-editUser"));
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".modal-editUser-body").html('');
        $(".modal-editUser-body").addClass('loader');
        $("#modal-editUser").modal('show');

        $.post('@routes.Application.postEditContactDetails()',
                {id: $(this).attr('data-id') },
                function(html) {
                    $(".modal-editUser-body").removeClass('loader');
                    $(".modal-editUser-body").html(html);
                }
        );
    });
</script>
```

and the hidden modal:

```
<div id="modal-editUser" class="hide">
    <div class="modal-editUser-body">
        <p> This is the modal body.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What javascript are you using to hide the modal?

Comment: @joshhunt That may be the problem, all I have is this in the modal footer: `<div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span5 offset2">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`

Comment: So can you do something like `$('#modal-editUser').on('click', '.btn-primary', function(e) {
$('#modal-editUser').modal('hide')`? Perhaps it is best to set up a fiddle or show an example page so I can see what is going on?

Comment: i'll give that a shot and post a fiddle if that doesn't do it, thanks!

Comment: It appears this was due to a script I included on the modal: `<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")"></script>` when I remote that, it works. Maybe some conflict with bootstrap causes it to stop working.